# Classe controle coneção internet Android - Wifi-3G

Tags: android, android-activity

Olá.

Atualmente eu controlo tela por tela o tipo de conexão de internet a qual o usuario está ou não conectado.

Utilizo um método semelhante a esse:

```
    /*Check conection*/
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //For 3G check
        final boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //For WiFi Check
        boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                .isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!is3g && !isWifi){

            Toast.makeText(AgendamentoActivity.this, "Sem conexão!! Verifique...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

}
```

Eu gostaria de saber como poderia criar uma classe unica para isso e chamála nas Activity que preciso controlar isso.

Não tenho muita experiência nisso e até encontrei alguns modelos mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Você quer criar um model que quando instanciado verifique essa conexão?

Comment: Isso, pra não precisar cada vez inserir um trecho de código repetido. @GuilhermeCostamilam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só criar um classe normal com esse método, e chamar no construtor:

```
public class Conexao {
    private boolean wifi;
    private boolean movel;

    public Conexao() {
        verificarConexao();
    }

    public boolean getWifi() {
        return wifi;
    }

    public boolean getMovel() {
        return movel;
    }

    private void verificarConexao() {
       ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //For 3G check
        movel = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //For WiFi Check
        wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!is3g && !isWifi) {
            Toast.makeText(AgendamentoActivity.this, "Sem conexão!! Verifique...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Quando instaciar vai ser atribuido o `true` ou `false` às variáveis, daí é só pegar com o get

Comment: Que método é esse `getSystemService()`?

Comment: Não sei, já estava nos códigos pergunta

Comment: Então, se não sabe, é porque esse método não pertence à classe que você escreveu(Conexao). Assim sendo, como é possível estar a ser usado lá dessa forma? Esse código não compilará.

Comment: Eu fiz um exemplo supondo que o código dado pelo autor funcionava apenas com aquilo, se ele não colocou o código dele completo não funcionará mesmo, mas não vou criar um projeto novo no Android Studio (que é muito lento), apenas para testar um código que, segundo o autor, está funcoinando

Comment: A questão não tem nada a ver com o código dele. O problema é que, qualquer que seja o código, uma classe não pode usar, dessa forma, um método que não esteja declarado nela. Note que a minha intenção não é "botar defeito", ela é apenas pedagógica.

Comment: dei uma olhada e aparentemente o método `getSystemService()` é da classe `ConnectivityManager`, se for o código está correto

Comment: Então, o que é necessário fazer para que esse objecto possa ser usado na classe Conexao?

Comment: Importar, não coloco import por não ser nescessário

Comment: `getSystemService()` é um método da classe Context. Para poder usá-lo a classe *Conexao* terá de receber um objecto Context no construtor e guardá-lo num atributo para ser usado quando necessitar de chamar o método.